# MySQL query with multiple OR conditions and a single AND condition

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQQL database table in which I dynamicly build the SQL statement with PHP based on some user input.

The SQL end up looking something like this....

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE item_status =  'Glass Bending - Andy'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Bren'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Gary'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - James'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Oscar'
AND (
`backing_cut` =0
)
```

Basically DB column `item_status` can be any of them and column `backing_cut` can be 0 or 1.

With this SQL above, it returns all the records matching the `item_status` values regardless of there `backing_cut` value.

It should allow me to filter out records from the result based on the `backing_cut` being a value of 0 or 1.

What am I doing wrong?

In addition to above SQL I also tried....

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE item_status =  'Glass Bending - Andy'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Bren'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Gary'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - James'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Oscar'
AND `backing_cut` =0
```

AND

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE item_status =  'Glass Bending - Andy'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Bren'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Gary'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - James'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Oscar'
(
    AND `backing_cut` =0
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parentheses

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE (item_status =  'Glass Bending - Andy'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Bren'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Gary'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - James'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Oscar')
AND (`backing_cut` = 0 OR `backing_cut` = 1 OR `backing_bent` = 0 OR `backing_bent` = 1)
```

you could also use value in array as

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE `item_status` IN  ('Glass Bending - Andy','Glass Bending - Bren','Glass Bending - Gary','Glass Bending - James','Glass Bending - Oscar')
AND (`backing_cut` = 0 OR `backing_cut` = 1 OR `backing_bent` = 0 OR `backing_bent` = 1)
```

you could then build your array using php and simply do something like:

```
$options = array('Glass Bending - Andy','Glass Bending - Bren','Glass Bending - Gary','Glass Bending - James','Glass Bending - Oscar');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `nam_order_items` WHERE `item_status` IN ({implode(',', $options}) AND (`backing_cut` = 0 OR `backing_cut` = 1 OR `backing_bent` = 0 OR `backing_bent` = 1)";
```

Edited to add option for backing cut = 1 or 0

Comment: This works! I couldnt seem to get them in the right location.  I need to add 1 more filter condition... ``backing_cut` =0` needs to act as... ``backing_cut` =0|1 OR `backing_bent` =0|1` can you assist with that addition?  thank you

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want `backing_cut = 0 or backing_cut = 1 or backing_bent = 0 or backing_bent = 1` ?updated to add more filter conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A conjunction has precedence over a disjunction, so

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE item_status =  'Glass Bending - Andy'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Bren'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Gary'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - James'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Oscar'
AND `backing_cut` =0
```

AND

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE item_status =  'Glass Bending - Andy'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Bren'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Gary'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - James'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Oscar'
(
    AND `backing_cut` =0
)
```

are semantically identical.  You have to use brackets to group the disjunctions to take precedence over the conjunction:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `nam_order_items` 
WHERE item_status =  ('Glass Bending - Andy'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Bren'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Gary'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - James'
OR item_status =  'Glass Bending - Oscar' )
AND `backing_cut` = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Sadly I have to first goole `conjunction` and `disjunction`!

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to understand why so think about operators in terms you familiar with.

The `OR` and `AND` operators precedence is like `+` and `*`.

So if you do `1 + 1 + 1 * 2` or `1 + 1 + 1 * (2)` or `1 + 1 + 1 (* 2)` the result is always `4`. The `*` is always first operator to execute.
If you want the result to be `6` then you need `(1 + 1 + 1) * 2`.